# I'm trying to link the post created by the specific user account in Django

Tags: python, django, web

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
##    phone = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=250)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(default='default_pic.png',null=True,blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class Task(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['complete']
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def taskCreate(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.customer = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('tasks')
    else:
        form = TaskForm()

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'todo_list/task_create.html',context)
```

Error:
ValueError at /create_task/
Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: Dominic>>": "Task.customer" must be a "Customer" instance.

I am trying to link the username in the user account to be shown on the model Task.customer that represents the post is created by that user. May I ask any methods could be done in order to specify the `customer` in the model `Task`? Also I do not understand the error message in detail because my admin panel already has the current username in the Customer model. However if I used `request.user.customer` the username does not show up instead returning None so how to solve this issue?

Comment: Be specific about your problem... Too many questions, too many probabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know `form.instance.customer = request.user`
but I think I understood what you meant and the below code does the same thing

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def taskCreate(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            t = form.save(commit = False)
            t.customer = request.user  # assigning current user to created task.customer
            t.save()
            return redirect('tasks')
    else:
        form = TaskForm()

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'todo_list/task_create.html',context)
```

if the code is still not working then try changing your line

`customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)` to

`customer = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)` in your **models.py**

Comment: I tried to change into the above but still cannot return the username of the account

Comment: Do I have to create an object before assigning a variable?

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the following snippet
form.instance.customer = request.user

request.user is not a Customer instance, you can try extracting the information from request.user and create a Customer object from it and then assign it back